# prevent casting of int when calling function

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I have the following code:

```
void foo(int64_t x) {}
void bar(int64_t* x) {}

int main() {
    int32_t a = 3;
    foo(a);
    bar(&a);
}
```

When I try to compile this, it gives an error that cannot convert `int32_t*` to `int64_t*`,
which is what I want.

Is it possible to get some similar errors when I try to invoke `foo(a)` ?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e3defa4902f44ad)?

Comment: Why do you want such error? As already mentioned, this conversion is always safe. If you were converting `int64_t` to `int32_t`, you could get an error by using a non-narrowing conversion: `foo({a})`

Comment: To expand on the comment by @alexeykuzmin0, what is the *actual* problem that you try to solve? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want the function to accept `int64_t` only (i.e. not cast anything else to int64_t automatically). I think the template specialization approach is quite nice

Comment: This is **not** about casting. It's about **converting**. A cast is one way to get a conversion, but it is not the only way.

Comment: So, you want `foo(3)` to fail on systems with 32-bit `int`, but succeed on systems with 64-bit `int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround you can overload *foo* with the deleted version:

```
void foo(int32_t x) = delete;
void foo(int64_t x) {}
```

---

As a more general solution you may create a deleted function template and then specialize it for *int64_t* (thanks to @Someprogrammerdude):

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) = delete;

template<>
void foo(int64_t x) {}
```

Interestingly, it doesn't compile with [clang 3.8](https://godbolt.org/g/HcZYBs), but compiles fine with [clang 3.9](https://godbolt.org/g/UlMyjd) and [gcc 6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/ePc8Kg).

Comment: And if the OP want to disallow *anything* but the `int64_t` argument function, then templates and template specialization could be used.

Comment: It still accepts `int` or whatever. You should delete all the possible overloads. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not if you code it on the lines of what @Someprogrammerdude is saying.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a template and a `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T x) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int64_t, T>::value, "!");
    // ...
}
```

Or a full specialization, where the primary template isn't defined or is deleted:

```
template<typename>
void foo(T);

// This should be fine as well
//
// template<typename>
// void foo(T) = delete;

template<>
void foo(int64_t x) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature to

`void foo(int64_t& x)`

then, because an `int32_t` cannot *bind* to a non-`const` reference to an `int64_t`, compilation will fail.

But this technique suffers from the fact that now `foo` *could* modify a variable passed to it through the reference. Naturally you could control that in `foo` itself, but on the whole it doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Note also that it can't bind to an anonymous temporary of even the correct type, e.g. `foo((int64_t)1);`

Comment: @M.M I've pinched that. The only credibility I feel this answer does have is that it works for pre C++11.